# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop while rendering all pdf pages with PDF.JS

Tags: reactjs, pdf.js

I'm writing a wrapper on pdf.js in React. First, I load the pdf document with `getDocument()`, then I render each page with a dedicated component that creates a canvas and paints the pdf file (according to `pdf.js API`). Everything is working properly, the only issue is the error in the console:

> Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

What could be the key of each pdf page? There seems to be no unique key to a page.

I tried `uniqueId()` of `lodash`; it did not work from some reason. I tried `new Date().getTime()`, and also tried giving each key the array index, but I get the same error.

```
{[...Array(this.state.numberOfPages)].map((_, page) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
   <PdfRenderer 
// im a component that does pdfDocument.getPage(currentPage)
     key={page}
     pdfDocument={this.state.pdfDocument}
     currentPage={page}
     scale={currentScale}
   />
  {this.renderLoading()}
</div>
);
})}
```

Comment: Key should be on the highest component in the map. i.e - div.

<div key={page}... /> should sort this out

Comment: Ho wow. I will try that out when home again! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the `key` prop to the `<div>` instead of the `<PdfRenderer>`, as the `<div>` is the actual child element.

```
<div key={page}>
  <PdfRenderer
    pdfDocument={this.state.pdfDocument}
    currentPage={page}
    scale={currentScale}
  />
</div>
```